# Recovery of IoT devices containing a single expired CA certificate

Tags: apache, ssl, iot, lets-encrypt

I have several cellular connected devices in difficult to reach locations that make hourly connection attempts to a server.  The devices only have 1 CA cert in firmware and are configured to perform server authentication against this cert.  The devices cannot connect to the Internet.  The LetsEncrypt CA cert on the devices is valid:

```
notBefore=Sep 30 21:12:19 2000 GMT
notAfter=Sep 30 14:01:15 2021 GMT
```

The devices are configured to perform server authentication to the host.  Client authentication is not performed by the host.

I have a LetsEncrypt host cert and key that is valid:

```
notBefore=Jun 24 18:03:19 2020 GMT
notAfter=Sep 22 18:03:19 2020 GMT
```

If I'm able to get the devices to connect, I can send a command to disable server authentication and eventually update the CA cert on each device over the air.

On the server, I've tried putting in place the host cert along with appropriate intermediates, CA cert and key.   I disabled NTP on the server and set back the clock to Jun 25, 2020.  Then while watching the TLS packets, I still see `Certificate Expired` message from the devices after the TLSv1.2 `Certificate, Server Hello Done` from the server.

It appears that the devices maintain their own clock.  I see the correct real time in their `Client Hello` message.  This time stamp is included in the `Random` field.  The same field in the `Server Hello` message contains a time stamp that is different with each TLS stream and meaningless, for example: `Dec 18, 2093 13:01:25.000000000 PST`.  I'm not clear if that onboard clock is used to validate the stored CA cert.

Is there any hope this method, or any other, can recover the devices?  Is there any apache config that might help or am I wasting my time?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly. You can update the CA on the device, but you only have an expired certificate for the server? The obvious solution then would be to get a still valid certificate for the server, issued by the (updated CA) which is trusted on the device.

Comment: I can't update the CA on the device until it connects to the server.   It is the CA on the device which has expired and the device will no longer authenticate to the server with this expired CA.   These devices are in remote locations.  They only attempt to communicate to a single server via cellular, once per hour.

Comment: *I'm not clear if that onboard clock is used to validate the stored CA cert.* If any external source is used it would be a potential security problem. I'd say it's hopeless unless you know of a zero-day and can hack your way onto the devices.